# Export data from sqoop to couchbase 5.0

Tags: hive, couchbase, sqoop

I have a use-case where I need to upload 20 million rows in couchbase from hive table using sqoop.
In couchbase documentation, I found couchbase Hadoop connector 1.2 which is for couchbase 2, whereas I am using couchbase5.0. 
Can anyone suggest if an upgraded connector is available now?
Or any alternative way of achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [latest documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/hadoop-1.2/hadoop.html):

> The Couchbase Hadoop Connector has reached End-of-Life (EOL) support.
>   We recommend existing Hadoop integrations to migrate to a supported
>   version of the [Couchbase Kafka Connector](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/kafka/kafka-intro.html). Additionally, the Couchbase
>   Hadoop Connector is not compatible with Couchbase Server 5.x; because
>   it relies on the TAP feed API which has been removed in Couchbase
>   Server 5.x in favor of the DCP feed.

If you can't use Kafka for some reason, then one possible solution would be to use the connector with an older version of Couchbase, and then connect that Couchbase cluster to a different cluster running Couchbase Server 5.x using [XDCR](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/xdcr/xdcr-intro.html).

Another solution might be to use [Apache Nifi](http://nifi.apache.org/) (which can connect just about anything, including Couchbase).

These solutions aren't officially supported by Couchbase (except for the [Kafka connector](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/kafka/kafka-intro.html)), so you're on your own.